# Typescript: is there a way to not require object if all props are optional?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on some library (kind of API proxy) that will be used in other internal projects. I'd like to define methods so it will easy to use, but I have a hard time with type assertions:

First I have a factory for all endpoint methods:

```js
export type Params<TQueryParams> = {
  customConfig?: object;
  fullResponse?: boolean;
} & (TQueryParams extends undefined ? { queryParams?: undefined } : { queryParams: TQueryParams })

export const getFactory = <
  TQueryParams extends object | undefined = undefined
>({ path }: any) => async (
  { queryParams, customConfig, fullResponse = false }: Params<TQueryParams>
): Promise<any> => {
  // some irrelevant factory code
  return {};
};
```

I already used some magic so depending on `TQueryParams` it will be required or not, but it's not enough.

So now when I want to define all endpoints and use the factory:

```js
// Case 1 - no interface
export const getFile = getFactory({
  path: '/api/file'
});

// I'd like for this one to not throw error
getFile();
// These will not throw error - as intended
getFile({});
getFile({
  fullResponse: true
});
// This will throw error - as intended
getFile({
  queryParams: {}
});
```

```js
// Case 2 - interface with all optional props
export interface ImageQueryParams {
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

export const getImage = getFactory<ImageQueryParams>({
  path: '/api/image'
});

// All of them should be ok, but only last will not throw error
getImage();
getImage({});
getImage({
  fullResponse: true
});
getImage({
  queryParams: {}
});
```

```js
// Case 3 - interface with mandatory props
export interface DataQueryParams {
  id: number;
  sort?: string;
}

export const getData = getFactory<DataQueryParams>({
  path: '/api/data'
});

// All will throw error - as intended
getData();
getData({});
getData({
  fullResponse: true
});
getData({
  queryParams: {}
});
// This one will not throw error - as intended
getData({
  queryParams: {
    id: 2131241
  }
});
```

Only case 3 works as intended.

I'd like especially achieve a solution when if there is no interface or it contains all optional props I will be able to pass nothing (`getImage();`) and be fine.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Params<TQueryParams>%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20customConfig%3F%3A%20object%3B%0D%0A%20%20fullResponse%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20(TQueryParams%20extends%20undefined%20%3F%20%7B%20queryParams%3F%3A%20undefined%20%7D%20%3A%20%7B%20queryParams%3A%20TQueryParams%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20getFactory%20%3D%20<%0D%0A%20%20TQueryParams%20extends%20object%20%7C%20undefined%20%3D%20undefined%0D%0A>(%7B%20path%20%7D%3A%20any)%20%3D>%20async%20(%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20queryParams%2C%20customConfig%2C%20fullResponse%20%3D%20false%20%7D%3A%20Params<TQueryParams>%0D%0A)%3A%20Promise<any>%20%3D>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20some%20irrevelant%20factory%20code%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case%201%20-%20no%20interface%0D%0Aexport%20const%20getFile%20%3D%20getFactory(%7B%0D%0A%20%20path%3A%20'%2Fapi%2Ffile'%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I'd%20like%20for%20this%20one%20to%20not%20throw%20error%0D%0AgetFile()%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20These%20will%20not%20throw%20error%20-%20as%20intended%0D%0AgetFile(%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0AgetFile(%7B%0D%0A%20%20fullResponse%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20will%20throw%20error%20-%20as%20intended%0D%0AgetFile(%7B%0D%0A%20%20queryParams%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case%202%20-%20interface%20with%20all%20optional%20props%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20ImageQueryParams%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20width%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20height%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20getImage%20%3D%20getFactory<ImageQueryParams>(%7B%0D%0A%20%20path%3A%20'%2Fapi%2Fimage'%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20All%20of%20them%20should%20be%20ok%2C%20but%20only%20last%20will%20not%20throw%20error%0D%0AgetImage()%3B%0D%0AgetImage(%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0AgetImage(%7B%0D%0A%20%20fullResponse%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0AgetImage(%7B%0D%0A%20%20queryParams%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20DataQueryParams%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20sort%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case%203%20-%20interface%20with%20mandatory%20props%0D%0Aexport%20const%20getData%20%3D%20getFactory<DataQueryParams>(%7B%0D%0A%20%20path%3A%20'%2Fapi%2Fdata'%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20All%20will%20throw%20error%20-%20as%20intended%0D%0AgetData()%3B%0D%0AgetData(%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0AgetData(%7B%0D%0A%20%20fullResponse%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0AgetData(%7B%0D%0A%20%20queryParams%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20one%20will%20not%20throw%20error%20-%20as%20intended%0D%0AgetData(%7B%0D%0A%20%20queryParams%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%202131241%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

Comment: I don't see any [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in your question; maybe you're thinking of something else?  "type definition" or "type declaration" or something?  ‍♂️

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was under impression that everything that includes `<>` is type assertion. If it's confusing, I can change the title and tag.

Comment: I guess [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) is what you're talking about, then.  In a generic type, the `<...>` represents not a type assertion but a [type parameter list](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cfb0adeadf1f21b5f8201cb2c0765f3f4467633f/doc/spec.md#361-type-parameter-lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not overjoyed about these type definitions (I was hoping for something more streamlined and general) but they seem to work for your use cases:

```
type CanBeOmitted<T, Y = T, N = never> =
  {} extends T ? Y : // T is weak (all props are optional), or
  undefined extends T ? Y : // T can be undefined
  N;
```

The type alias `CanBeOmitted<T, Y, N>` checks if `T` is either an all-optional object type (also called a ["weak type"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#weak-type-detection)) or an `undefined`-compatible type.  If so, it returns `Y`; if not, it returns `N` (which defaults to `never`).  We can use this a few times to build up your `Params` type.

Here it is:

```
export type Params<TQueryParams> =
  CanBeOmitted<TQueryParams, [undefined?]> |
  [
    {
      customConfig?: object,
      fullResponse?: boolean
    } & (
      { queryParams: TQueryParams } |
      CanBeOmitted<TQueryParams, { queryParams?: never }>
    )
  ];
```

One thing I've done differently is made it a tuple type containing the parameter.  If the parameter can be omitted completely, an [optional tuple](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) is returned.

Here's `getFactory`:

```
export const getFactory = <
  TQueryParams extends object | undefined = undefined
>({ path }: any) => async (
  ...args: Params<TQueryParams>
): Promise<any> => {
    // get rid of conditional types
    const arg = args[0] as {
      customConfig?: object,
      fullResponse?: boolean,
      queryParams?: TQueryParams
    } | undefined;
    const queryParams = arg ? arg.queryParams : undefined;
    const customConfig = arg ? arg.customConfig : undefined;
    const fullResponse = (arg ? arg.fullResponse : undefined) || false;
    // some irrelevant factory code
    return {};
  };
```

Note that `Params<TQueryParams>` is being used as a [rest tuple](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) instead of as a single parameter.  When that tuple is optional, it allows the return value of `getFactory()` to be called with zero arguments.  Also note that we can no longer assume that the parameter exists, so we have to change how to get `queryParams`, `customConfig`, and `fullResponse` as variables inside the implementation.

Okay, let's see how this works:

```
// Case 1 - no interface
export const getFile = getFactory({
  path: '/api/file'
});

getFile(); // okay
getFile({}); // okay
getFile({
  fullResponse: true
}); // okay
getFile({
  queryParams: {}
}); // error, {} is not undefined

// Case 2 - interface with all optional props
export interface ImageQueryParams {
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

export const getImage = getFactory<ImageQueryParams>({
  path: '/api/image'
});

getImage(); // okay
getImage({}); // okay
getImage({
  fullResponse: true
}); // okay
getImage({
  queryParams: {}
}); // okay

export interface DataQueryParams {
  id: number;
  sort?: string;
}

// Case 3 - interface with mandatory props
export const getData = getFactory<DataQueryParams>({
  path: '/api/data'
});

getData(); // error, expected 1 arg
getData({}); // error, queryParams missing
getData({
  fullResponse: true
}); // error, queryParams missing
getData({
  queryParams: {}
}); // error, id missing
getData({
  queryParams: {
    id: 2131241
  }
}); // okay
```

I *think* that's what you're looking for.  Okay, hope that helps you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgOwEIQPIFsCWxgQCYA8AKgDRQCaUAvFKVAHLVQIQBuEATgHzUBQUUAN4BfKBAAeuBHgDOtKAH4KUAFxQA9OvmY5AdwhwA1lAAUcADbmoYDgHswcuB2j3gmWwgsBKMrY78oAFdpCAAzTBY8MUkIaTkiRWU1TXkAY0QoACNoYLwwiPwA+gBuXl4JMD9gKFBIKAAFJzh0GWIARUDOEEaOZpkeKgD4ZDQsHHx2zo5uppayAG1c-MiFAF0eAB8A+YCBQV2BKFTAmWBbdBgPcIBzBTVbTIArCFTgEgOBUMDLACUIGUqCBkEDuWVstnMBgQB1EADJTB8hFAAI5TGa9FpqIgdLo9PpQURbQ6HYYoDDYXCEbFovFzJGo3GzGSgljsDgErgHLwBValcriSocaqpDynKDXCDAABicFefhATAIAWpjIxcgkUlkUAez1eUA2QRC4UiTCWxsKXBMgmscGAAAsCWpECAvNQeHAZCAEKkEQIAHQBpzXGRqWmtFXTMOcryhuxYYEEZ0DHj7YkpCXVDiYKK2UJHDx4bDuTxWWr-A4ioHVINMIMyeYABlWUA9QkRx1O50uCBuoJ1LzeiK+v3+gOBoMy4MhiHexIEDMjTNBEfRfRh+sNeXNeFKxMrYoXq5atY410SQb9h7Dqk3y3wu8O++FJzOFyumDPNBrSgvHdf3ZuG8zQKHcK1Faph3MP4AVFaAaDMU9z1PP1IOgsdoDUYDIldDYDVCCxgQfAQUhkc5oEwDhnEhVhEAg2UzmmfM8gOZxgECDgECEYQH24soUngYEoAARigABaZhbCgCJcA4fDUggflBWFcDxUlKVMEhJgMxlOVpitAIwFtO01AAcnUOAwEwdRwkhEzeGELw+W0jSIBMRyNC0WxDDgEBeGcyErQc4oPO1bzfP81zUygVDR1gtRgA4Tp7PclIvJ8vy1Jc-T5xpJk1BEZLgpSTg7A4MgRCkuQEFsaosMKXh+I9aAACYxKkhAZLk6BdGwB0LCsVxiwsaw7AcRSqnazrZWgABJdA4AlHFFzVNsBB6vB7RZQJ0GyDgHztCAPztYAtp2zhSmEMoKgmp9VOAOaFrgu6dIYkACAexbcrVS0osM+1TPMyz1EweaJTsoKygzD7XJSzywoy+7QcioKQrS8LJWh7Lou+KDYqBCB4sShSUdS+GoaRrGrzyrjCtR+HxqFSbOC6qAABFbTgJajzkKLszUBBtt2h9SKFUFTizBBrguvitAE6AAGY2uk5npqgHr7SgebpFteURvsGQGeUqs7vZ4A4C0tT6PlAhTc5r6+h+gyjIBiyrLwDnwccyHJVttyiq0Eq-DICoB3wYSW1PBHfZEWGxEooOUXt494xkCJrijjmsZimD8cJpKSYD+OysT1V8RTtOM7Nymk5DGmC7j0qyGzTWdFTyXK7gavS8xVbDj5qBmqE+WhOagAWISAku+u0aAA)

Comment: Does it help me? This is some serious witchcraft :D That is more than perfect. I can't thank you enough!

One question though...isn't this overkill?
`const fullResponse = (arg ? arg.fullResponse : undefined) || false;`
I think this will suffice:
`const fullResponse = (arg ? arg.fullResponse : false);`

Comment: `arg.fullResponse` may be `undefined`, since `{ fullResponse?: boolean }` is equivalent to `{ fullResponse?: boolean | undefined }`.  So, assuming you want `fullResponse` to be a `boolean`, then you need to check that also.  Of course if you just want something truthy/falsy, then you can just leave it as `(arg ? all.fullResponse: false)` and treat `undefined` as `false`.  It's up to you.